# Cannot add an Exchange account to Outlook 2016 on OS X El Capitan

Tags: email, ms-office, macos, exchange

I recently installed Office 2016 on my MacBook Pro Late 2011, OS X El Capitan. I'd like to add my Exchange account to Outlook. My domain is @ofsl.ie.

I added the email and password and I clicked on add account. I got an error message error saying:

> Outlook for Mac cannot add this type of account; to open your account please open your browser and open an Office 365 session and then use the Outlook web app.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Outlook 2016 will not connect to anything earlier than an Exchange 2010 server and it sounds like that is likely an Exchange 2007 (or earlier) server.

If this is the case than you are outta luck until that mail server is upgraded to Exchange 2010, 2013 or 2016. Either that or downgrade to the previous version of Office for the mac.